# Overload ++ and + operators

Tags: c++

Why can I overload and use `++` operator in LHS and RHS while `+` one works just in LHS mode?

```
class B {
public:

    string operator ++ () { return "hello"; }
    string operator + () {  return "hello2"; }
};

int main ()
{
    B b;
    string s = +b ;
    s = b+ ; // compile error syntax error : ';'    

    s = b++; 
    s = ++b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because "b+" is an invalid statement for that operator, overload or not

Comment: C defines unary `+` only in a prefix form, while `++` and `--` are defined in both prefix and postfix forms. C++ allows you to specify what will execute for a give expression, but doesn't change the basic syntax for what's allowed or not, so you still only get a prefix form of unary `+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overloaded operators can only be used with the same syntax as the corresponding built-in ones. The built-in `++` is defined as either a prefix or postfix operator; the built-in `+` is only defined as a prefix operator (and of course as a binary operator).

Note that your code won't compile even without the `b+` line, since you're missing a postfix version of `++`:

```
string operator ++ (int) { return "postfix"; }
```

Comment: My visual c++ compiles my code without problems. But when I have included your line I got different behavior (that was expected). But why is (int) is used for? And why not char for example?

Comment: @vico: I've no idea why VC++ might accept it, but a more standard compiler doesn't: http://ideone.com/oiIzga. `(int)` is the way you indicate the postfix form. There's no particular reason why that was chosen rather than `char` or whatever; but `int` was chosen, so that's what we have to use.

Comment: It appears that VC++ allows the use of the postfix operator if you have defined the prefix operator (and gives it the same behavior), but issues a warning ([C4620](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12waye2f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

> Why I can overload and use ++ operator in LHS and RHS

Your code actually [produces two errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20eed4f98326d179):

```
main.cpp:16:12: error: expected expression
    s = b+ ; // compile error syntax error : ';'    
           ^
main.cpp:18:10: error: cannot increment value of type 'B'
    s = b++; 
        ~^
```

So you actually haven't overloaded the post-increment operator, only the pre-increment operator. Your question remains, however, since you *could* overload post-increment if you wanted to but C++ does not offer any similar syntax for overloading a postfix unary plus operator.

C++ does not change the way operators in expressions are parsed based on operator overloads. It will only allow you to overload operators that already exist, and those operators will be parsed exactly as if operator overloads do not exist. It's only after parsing that C++ will then look around for operator overloads to figure out what the parsed expression means. Thus C++ offers a way to overload a post-increment operator because it already handles parsing the post-increment operator, but it does not already handle parsing a postfix plus operator.

Limiting C++ operator overloads to existing operators was done because it is simpler to implement a parser if the parser doesn't have watch out for arbitrary uses of operators. That doesn't mean it can't be done, however. The language Swift, for example, allows arbitrary operator overloading for binary, prefix unary, and postfix unary operators, including creating [completely new operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_84).